# Laravel Datatable don´t work, returns Fatal Error Exception

Tags: laravel, datatables

I trying to use the laravel datatables in my project, but for some reason I get a strange error. When I do a normal ajax request it´s ok. When I make the normal datatable using just the plugin it´s ok.

Anyone can help me?

This is my view:

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('title','Balconistas')

@section('content')
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="allposts">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
@stop

@push('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#allposts').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{{url('datatable')}}',
            columns: [
                {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                {data: 'description', name: 'description'},
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
@endpush
```

This is my web.php (file routes)

```
Route::get('datatable', function () {
        return Datatables::of(QuizTopic::all())->make(true);
    });
```

I got this error:

```
FatalErrorException in Model.php line 3351:
Call to a member function connection() on null
```

[image: FatalErrorException in Model.php line 3351:Call to a member function connection() on null]

--- Edit

I configured my connections on .env file,

```
DB_CONNECTION=foo
DB_HOST=99.9.9.98
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=foo
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

I set configuration on database.php file

```
'foo' => [
                'driver'    => 'mysql',
                'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
                'port'      => env('DB_PORT'),
                'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
                'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
                'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
                'strict'    => true,
                'engine'    => NULL,
            ],
```

My QuizTopic Model file,

```
namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

    class QuizTopic extends Model
    {
        protected $table   = 'quiz_topics';
        protected $guarded = ['id'];
        protected $hidden  = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];


        use SoftDeletes;

        public function questions()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\QuizQuestion', 'rel_topics_questions', 'topic_id', 'question_id');
        }
    }
```

But the error persists.

Comment: have you configured your database correctly? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration Try setting the default connection and testing things out again. Note: check you `.env` file

Comment: First of all, you have to provide a proper configuration values in .env file to connect to database. and then you should try. Your error seems like you have not set your connection string in .env file or config/database.php file

Comment: Please post the code for you `QuizTopic` model

Comment: @melanholly I configured the .env file, but the problems persists.

Comment: @AmitKumar I configured the .env file, but the problems persists.

Comment: @Jerodev I put the file.

Comment: I am using laravel 5.3

Comment: try reinstalling laravel somewhere else and see if the problem continues